# Persisting child objects before adding to parent results in very slow update

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-performance

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM.
I have a `Parent` class and a `Child` class. `Parent` and `Child` are in a one-to-many relationship. A `Parent` has many children, potentially even 20k-30k.

Here's how my classes are set up

```
class Parent(Base):
__tablename__ = "parent"

id = mapped_column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


# associations
children = relationship(
    "Child",
    back_populates="parent",
    uselist=True,
    cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.deleted_at == None)'
)


class Child(Base):
__tablename__ = "child"


id = mapped_column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

# associations:
parent_id = mapped_column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("parent.id",
                                                       ondelete="CASCADE"),
                                            nullable=True)
parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

The problem is that when I try to establish a one-to-many relationship between one Parent and 10k children, the flushing operation takes 2 MINUTES when ran against a real instance of a PostgresSQL database. (The database is running in a high performance server and my laptop has an excellent connection.)

Here's the code that I use for performance testing:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
session = session_maker()

parent = Parent()
session.add(parent)
session.flush() # fast
session.commit() # fast

children = []
for i in range(10000):
    child = Child()
    children.append(child)
session.add_all(children)
session.flush() # fast
session.commit() # fast


parent.children.extend(children)
for child in children:
    child.parent = parent
session.add(parent)
session.add_all(children)
session.flush() # super slow
session.commit() # super slow
```

What is weird to me is that I can create and flush 10k children in less than a second, but then when I need to establish a simple one-to-many relation it takes 2 minutes.

I refuse to believe this is normal.

**EDIT 1:**
I changed the testing script to this and now it's much faster:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
session = session_maker()

parent = Parent()
session.add(parent)

children = []
for _ in range(n_children):
    child = Child()
    children.append(child)
session.add_all(children)

assert len(children) == n_children

for child in children:
    child.parent = parent
parent.children.extend(children)
session.add(parent)
session.add_all(children)

# FLUSHING and COMMITTING:
start_time = time.time()

session.flush() # fast
session.commit()

print(time.time() - start_time)


for i in range(0, n_children - 1):
    assert children[i].id + 1 == children[i + 1].id
    assert children[i].parent == parent
assert len(parent.children) == n_children

session.close()
```

As you can see instead of flushing every time, I only flush once at the end.
Could someone explain why this is much faster?
Also this will cause some problems in my code as until flushing ids are not defined.

**EDIT 2:**
When establishing a one-to-many relationship between Parent and Child we are updating the parent_id column of the Child table. Therefore, we are essentially trying to perform 10k UPDATE operations. For some reason, SQLAlchemy is performing this operations sequentially, therefore going back and forth to the database 10k times. This theory is reinforced by the fact that if I use a local database the execution time is much faster (but still slow), around 10s.
Is there a way to perform the updates in a parallel way? I was looking at `session.bulk_update_mappings` but the execution time is still the same. Maybe there are some parameters for the engine

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? With version 2.0.19 I can create and persist a parent with 10_000 child objects in less than 10 seconds without any fancy tricks. Code [here](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/50244fce9d35f6e791c8664822cac381).

Comment: I am using version 2.0.9. In your code you are creating the parent and the children together. Try first to create the Parent and the Children separately, flushing and committing. Then try to associate the Parent and Children, flushing and committing.

Comment: What I think it's happening is that when creating a one-to-many relationship, you are basically updating the parent_id column of the Child table. So we need to perform 10k UPDATE operations. For some reason SQLAlchemy is executing each update operation separately, therefore going back and forth to the database 10k times.

Comment: If you create 10_000 parent-less child rows via `flush()` and then associate those children with a parent, then yes, SQLAlchemy will have to update those 10_000 rows. However, it does not make 10_000 round-trips to do it. It calls the `executemany()` DBAPI method with a query like `UPDATE child SET parent_id=%(parent_id)s WHERE child.id = %(child_id)s` and parameters like `[{'parent_id': 1, 'child_id': 1}, {'parent_id': 1, 'child_id': 2}, …]`. That will still be slower than adding the children to the parent *before* doing the flush because SQLA can INSERT the child rows with the parent_id.

Comment: Correction: "it [SQLAlchemy] does not *necessarily* make 10_000 round-trips". It calls `executemany()` and the DBAPI layer decides how to apply the updates. In this case psycopg2 may in fact send 10_000 separate update statements. (psycopg2 has executemany() optimizations for inserts, but I'm not sure if it has something similar for updates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you persist the child objects before they have been associated with a parent, you insert the rows into the child table with `parent_id` as NULL. That is,

```py
num_children = 3

engine.echo = True
t0 = time.perf_counter()
with Session(engine) as sess:
    all_children = [Child() for i in range(num_children)]
    sess.add_all(all_children)
    sess.flush()
```

generates

```sql
INSERT INTO child (parent_id) SELECT p0::INTEGER FROM (VALUES (%(parent_id__0)s, 0), (%(parent_id__1)s, 1), (%(parent_id__2)s, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING child.id, child.id AS id__1
[generated in 0.00014s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] {'parent_id__0': None, 'parent_id__1': None, 'parent_id__2': None}
```

Then, when you associate them with a parent, SQLAlchemy has to update all of those child rows with actual parent_id.

```py
    sess.add(
        Parent(name="parent_a", children=all_children)
    )
    sess.commit()
```

SQLAlchemy creates the parent row

```sql
INSERT INTO parent (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING parent.id
[generated in 0.00045s] {'name': 'parent_a'}
```

and then calls the DBAPI `.executemany()` method to update the child rows

```sql
UPDATE child SET parent_id=%(parent_id)s WHERE child.id = %(child_id)s
[generated in 0.00038s] [{'parent_id': 1, 'child_id': 1}, {'parent_id': 1, 'child_id': 2}, {'parent_id': 1, 'child_id': 3}]
```

but a Wireshark trace shows that what psycopg2 actually sends to the server are separate UPDATE statements for each row

```sql
UPDATE child SET parent_id=1 WHERE child.id = 1
UPDATE child SET parent_id=1 WHERE child.id = 2
UPDATE child SET parent_id=1 WHERE child.id = 3
```

that is, one round-trip for each child row. That will obviously be slow for a large number of children.

Instead, associate the newly-created child objects to the parent *before* flushing, which creates the parent and then creates each child with the appropriate parent_id

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    all_children = [Child() for i in range(num_children)]
    sess.add(
        Parent(name="parent_a", children=all_children)
    )
    sess.commit()
```

which generates

```sql
INSERT INTO parent (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING parent.id
[generated in 0.00045s] {'name': 'parent_a'}
INSERT INTO child (parent_id) SELECT p0::INTEGER FROM (VALUES (%(parent_id__0)s, 0), (%(parent_id__1)s, 1), (%(parent_id__2)s, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING child.id, child.id AS id__1
[generated in 0.00017s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] {'parent_id__0': 1, 'parent_id__1': 1, 'parent_id__2': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

These do the same thing but the first one has to execute an UPDATE for each child whereas the second one does not need to do this.

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    # Uses INSERT statement to create parent, gets id back with RETURNING
    parent = Parent()
    session.add(parent)
    session.flush()

    # Uses INSERT statement to create childs
    childs = [Child(), Child()]
    session.add_all(childs)
    session.flush()

    # Uses UPDATE statement to set parent_id
    parent.children.extend(childs)
    session.flush()
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    # Uses INSERT statement to create parent, gets id back with RETURNING
    parent = Parent()
    session.add(parent)
    session.flush()

    # Uses INSERT statement to create childs (with parent_id already set)
    childs = [Child(parent=parent), Child(parent=parent)]
    session.add_all(childs)
    session.flush()

    session.commit()
```

Here is the echo output, it can be hard to read but you can see the inserts and updates in there.

```
2023-07-26 14:28:00,947 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-07-26 14:28:00,952 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO parents DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING parents.id
2023-07-26 14:28:00,953 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00060s] {}
2023-07-26 14:28:00,961 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO childs (parent_id) SELECT p0::INTEGER FROM (VALUES (%(parent_id__0)s, 0), (%(parent_id__1)s, 1)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING childs.deleted, childs.id, childs.id AS id__1
2023-07-26 14:28:00,962 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00029s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] {'parent_id__0': None, 'parent_id__1': None}
2023-07-26 14:28:00,980 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT childs.deleted AS childs_deleted, childs.id AS childs_id, childs.parent_id AS childs_parent_id 
FROM childs 
WHERE %(param_1)s = childs.parent_id AND childs.deleted IS NULL
2023-07-26 14:28:00,980 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00070s] {'param_1': 1}
2023-07-26 14:28:00,989 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE childs SET parent_id=%(parent_id)s WHERE childs.id = %(childs_id)s
2023-07-26 14:28:00,990 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00062s] [{'parent_id': 1, 'childs_id': 1}, {'parent_id': 1, 'childs_id': 2}]
2023-07-26 14:28:00,993 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-07-26 14:28:01,025 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-07-26 14:28:01,026 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO parents DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING parents.id
2023-07-26 14:28:01,026 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.07392s ago] {}
2023-07-26 14:28:01,032 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO childs (parent_id) SELECT p0::INTEGER FROM (VALUES (%(parent_id__0)s, 0), (%(parent_id__1)s, 1)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING childs.deleted, childs.id, childs.id AS id__1
2023-07-26 14:28:01,032 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.07063s ago (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] {'parent_id__0': 2, 'parent_id__1': 2}
2023-07-26 14:28:01,035 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: The statements are more confusing to read because executemany is being used as well.  You can turn `echo=True` on the engine and see the SQL which helps a lot to understand what is happening.